# Using pandas extract regex with multiple groups

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract a number from a pandas series of strings. For example consider this series:

```
s = pd.Series(['a-b-1', 'a-b-2', 'c1-d-5', 'c1-d-9', 'e-10-f-1-3.xl', 'e-10-f-2-7.s'])

0            a-b-1
1            a-b-2
2           c1-d-5
3           c1-d-9
4    e-10-f-1-3.xl
5     e-10-f-2-7.s
dtype: object
```

There are 6 rows, and three string formats/templates (known). The goal is to extract a number for each of the rows depending on the string. Here is what I came up with:

```
s.str.extract('a-b-([0-9])|c1-d-([0-9])|e-10-f-[0-9]-([0-9])')
```

and this correctly extracts the numbers that I want from each row:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   NaN NaN
1   2   NaN NaN
2   NaN 5   NaN
3   NaN 9   NaN
4   NaN NaN 3
5   NaN NaN 7
```

However, since I have three groups in the regex, I have 3 columns, and here comes the question:

Can I write a regex that has one group or that can generate a single column, or do I need to coalesce the columns into one, and how can I do that without a loop if necessary?

**Desired outcome would be a series like:**

```
0   1
1   2
2   5
3   9
4   3
5   7
```

Comment: Do you mean like switch the alternatives `(?:a-b|c1-d|e-10-f-[0-9])-([0-9])` https://regex101.com/r/GPFI94/1

Comment: Yes, thats the answer I'm looking for, put it as an answer if you'd like. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single capturing group at the end, and add the 3 prefixes in a on capturing group `(?:`

As they all end with a hyphen, you could move that to after the non capturing group to shorted it a bit.

```
(?:a-b|c1-d|e-10-f-[0-9])-([0-9])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPFI94/1)

```
s.str.extract('(?:a-b|c1-d|e-10-f-[0-9])-([0-9])')
```

*Ouput*

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  5
3  9
4  3
5  7
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest thing to do is `bfill\ffill`:

```
(s.str.extract('a-b-([0-9])|c1-d-([0-9])|e-10-f-[0-9]-([0-9])')
  .bfill(axis=1)
  [0]
)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    5
3    9
4    3
5    7
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Another way is to use optional non-capturing group:

```
s.str.extract('(?:a-b-)?(?:c1-d-)?(?:e-10-f-[0-9]-)?([0-9])')
```

Output:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  5
3  9
4  3
5  7
```